# Regex get the middle section of each word javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string

So essentially what I'm trying to do is loop through every word in a html document and replace the first letter of each word with 'A', the second - second last letter with 'b' and the last letter with 'c', completely replacing the word. I'm not sure if regular expressions are the way to go about doing this (should I instead be using for loops and checking each character?) however I'll ask anyway.

Currently I'm doing:

`document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\b(\w)/g, 'A');` to get the first letter of each word

`document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\w\b/g, 'c');` to get the last letter of each word

So if I had the string: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet` I can currently make it `Aorec Apsuc Aoloc Aic Amec` but I'd like to do `Abbbc Abbbc Abbbc Abc Abbc` in javascript.

Any help is much appreciated - regular expressions really confuse me.

Comment: why don't you just take the length of each word, build the new one with as much bbb as needed?

Comment: @rock321987 hmmm yeah hadn't though about that - I'll probably loop through and remove the words with 3 or less characters

Comment: @RaphaelMüller - yes probably should have gone that route (hence my mention of looping in the question) however i have been (attempting to) learn Regex from Treehouse and was interested in how you would go about doing it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost got it.

```js
str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"

str = str
  .replace(/\w/g, 'b')
  .replace(/\b\w/g, 'A')
  .replace(/\w\b/g, 'c')

document.write(str);
```

Fancier replacement rules can be handled with a callback function, e.g.

```js
str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"

str = str.replace(/\w+/g, function(word) {
  
  if (word === "dolor")
    return word;
  
  return 'A' + 'b'.repeat(word.length - 2) + 'c';

});

document.write(str);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, this doesn't relate directly to my question but just out of interest, if I wanted to exclude 'dolor' from my replacement, how would I do that in a multi-step regex statement?